# Container <container_name> not found for account <storage_account_name>.blob.core.windows.net

Tags: azure, hive, azure-blob-storage, azure-hdinsight

I am creating a table in `hive` using the command below:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE  azure_test_table
(
col1                      string,
col2                      string
)
STORED AS ORC
LOCATION 'wasbs://container_name@storage_account_name.blob.core.windows.net/directory/'
tblproperties ("orc.comlress"="ZLIB");
```

When I run `SELECT * FROM azure_test_table limit 1;` I am getting an error.

> Failed with exception
>   java.io.IOException:org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureException:
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureException: Container myntra in account
>   analyticsfe.blob.core.windows.net not found, and we can't create  it
>   using anoynomous credentials.

I have added the storage account properties in `hive-site.xml` like below:

```
<property>
  <name>fs.azure.account.key.storage_account_name.blob.core.windows.net</name>
  <value>access_key_for_the_account</value>
</property>
```

What am I missing?? Can you please help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the configuration through Ambari to create external table on hive which is mapped to Azure Blob storage as follows:

Storage accounts to the existing clusters can be added via Ambari by following below steps

**Step 1:** Go to Ambari dashboard https://clustername.azurehdinsight.net/

**Step 2:** Navigate to HDFS -->Config -->Advanced, scroll down to Custom core-site

[image]

**Step 3**: Select Add Property and enter your storage account name and key in following manner

**HDFS >>Custom core-site**

Key => fs.azure.account.key.(storage_account).blob.core.windows.net

Value => (Storage Access Key)

[image]

**Step 4:** Navigate to HIVE => Config => Advanced, scroll down to Custom hive-env

[image]

**Step 5**: Select Add Property and enter your storage account name and key in following manner

**Hive** =>> **Custom hive-env**

Key => AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT

Value => (Storage Account name)

Key => AZURE_STORAGE_KEY

Value => (Storage Access Key)

[image]

**Step 6**: Restart services from Ambari

[image]